# Text input's onClick handler isn't called when using accessibility tools

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a `<input readOnly={true} type="text"/>` element with an `onClick` handler and `onKeyDown` space and enter handler in React.

This handler is called correctly when using a mouse or a keyboard, but when using accessibility tools, like Android's `TalkBack`, it is never called.

I've tried:

- `role="button"`
- `role="combobox"` with `aria-haspopup="listbox"` etc.

Are there any props missing that would make this text input behave like a button?

Minimal react sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-silence-6bfwyu?file=/src/index.tsx).

Comment: Why do you want a text input to behave like a button? It's a hideously confusing UI even for someone who doesn't use AT.

Comment: That's a custom dropdown component that can also be searchable. But when searching is disabled it gets a `readonly` prop.
I get it that it might go against the rules, but first I'm trying to solve the problem without rewriting the component.

Comment: What do you mean by “using accessibility tools”? The basis for a lot of accessibility features is keyboard control. Is keyboard control implemented on that input? Can you open the dropdown by means of space, enter and arrow keys?
See [the Combobox pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/#keyboard-interaction-6) for some guidance.
The difference between `<button>` and an `<input>` is that natively the former will dispatch its `click` event on <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>. Adding `role=button` does not solve this.

Comment: I am talking of `VoiceOver` or `TalkBack` which exist on Apple or Android. My production code already had keyboard handlers, but I've also updated the sandbox link. Now it's possible to call the get an event with the keyboard on a computer, but on Android, neither `onKeyDown` nor `onClick` is dispatched.

Comment: Would you mind explaining this in your question to help others who have the same issue? Just for debugging, did you try `role=combobox aria-haspopup=listbox aria-controls=id of listbox`, or to actually use a `<button>`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, tried all of them but had no luck. I've updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

The basis for usability by means of screen readers is keyboard control.

Behaviour of a button includes keyboard interaction: It’s focusable and can be activated by means of <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd>. It can also be found via voice control by using it’s accessible name.

This behaviour is not added simply by adding an ARIA role. You will need to do it manually.

For the ability to focus the element you are already good, since `<input readonly>` already can receive focus.

But, you will need to add keyboard interaction yourself. The following is just an illustration, you would also need to make arrow keys and selection work.

Please refer to [the Combobox pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/) for guidance on how to implement keyboard interaction, and on which ARIA roles and states to use, most notably `aria-expanded` and `aria-haspopup`, which seem necessary for the keyboard events to work.

```
    role="combobox"
    aria-haspopup="it depends"
    aria-expanded={state goes here}
    onKeyDown={e => {
          if (isClosed && ["Space", "Enter", "ArrowDown", "ArrowUp"].includes(e.code)) {
            setText('open')
          } else if (isOpen && ["Escape", "Enter"].includes(e.code)) {
            setText('close')
    }}}
```